# API NAME ACCOUNT IS INVALID, DID YOU MEAN "USER?" -- Lightning recordEditForm --Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I am simply pasting the code from this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) :

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Account">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="AccountId" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the exact code that you pasted? I see no reference to Account in the above code. Also, is there a reason you are using the Aura component instead of the LWC one?

Comment: My bad, I corrected it, I pasted the code with Contact object but I am facing the issue with both objects. I am using Aura as per requirement.

Comment: In that case... that record Id is just a sample - I hope you are not using it. Get a real account id in there and try again.

Comment: Yes, i am using a real record id

Comment: There is no AccountId, FirstName or LastName field on Account.

Comment: This was oddly fixed when replacing the hardcoded record id i was using for test purposes with  recordId="{!v.recordId}"